# React With Formik and autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, typescript, autocomplete, formik

I need some advice to create an autocomplete text input. I am new to react. What I want to achieve is:

I have an object with several fields eg. Project, Kommission, recipe... I want to type in one of this properties and want to get the suggestions while typing into the input including this property’s. On select one, the text input should become the project value

I am using react with typescript, asp.net core for the backend

Thanks for any advice
Arga

Comment: It's very dificul to know what you need, can you make a running example here, with what you have? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-react-ts

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to use react-twitter-typeahead